# google analytics metrics and dimensions API question

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use google analytics API to retrieve some data to build a chart that displays number of visitor per day for current month.

However I'm almost completely lost with metrics and dimensions idea.

if I use ga:visitors metrics - that would only give me a total number of visitors - right?
How would I retrieve visitors per each day in a month?

any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I highly recommend using the Data Feed Query Explorer to get your feet wet:

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

You'll have to login with your Google Account and click the button to grant the application access.  But it has a simple UI that lets you build your request.  A good starting example might be:

- **dimensions:** ga:date
- **metrics:** ga:pageviews,ga:visitors

This will give you  pageviews and visitors per day, for every day in your date range.

The general idea is that you are building a table of sorts.  Metrics are what you are measuring, and Dimensions are what you are grouping the Metrics by.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I tried it but its returning the values only for one metric say ga:pageviews and I am not getting the results for ga.visitors. Any idea?

Comment: Wouldn't the metric "visitorsCount" be relevant in this context? Nice tip!